# Use calendar to set alarm notification android

Tags: android, notifications, android-alarms

I am trying to get a notification to pop up based on the user date and time they put in. Here is my code for getting the time values

```
        // String GetRawDate Gets The User Value For Date//
        String getRawDate = date.getText().toString();

        // String SplitDate Splits The Date Into Three Separate Ints//
        String[] splitDate = getRawDate.split("/");

        // Int GetMonth Gets The Value Of The Month//
        int getMonth = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]);

        // Int GetDay Gets The Value Of The Day//
        int getDay = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]);

        // Int GetYear Gets The Value Of The Year//
        int getYear = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]);

        // Get Military Start Time//
        String test = military_start_time;

        // Split It//
        String[] splitStartTime = test.split(":");

        // Get Hour In Integer Form
        int getHour = Integer.parseInt(splitStartTime[0]);

        // Get Minute In Integer Form//
        int getMinute = Integer.parseInt(splitStartTime[1]);
```

From here I add these values to calendar

```
        // Gets Calendar Instance//
        Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, getMonth);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, getYear);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, getDay);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getHour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getMinute);
```

Then I set my alarm

```
        // Intent To Start Notification After X Seconds//
        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
        alertIntent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
        alertIntent.putExtra("time", starttime.getText().toString());

        // Defines Alarm Manager//
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)   
        getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Sets Alarm Manager//
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, 
        alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        // Starts Activity ListView//
        Intent b = new Intent(this, Reminders.class);
        startActivity(b);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slid_in, R.anim.slid_out);
```

Say the user has the date of 6/4/15 and the Time 22:10 I want the notification to show up on this time. For some reason it shows up about 5 seconds after the code is run through. Anybody know what I am doing wrong with the alarm?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, 
    alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

P.S: Needs min API:19